# Consuming a queue based on its consumer count in Spring AMQP

Tags: java, spring-boot, rabbitmq, spring-amqp, spring-rabbit

I want a queue to be consumed by only one subscriber at a time. So if one subscriber drops, then another one(s) will have the chance of subscribing.

I am looking for the correct way of doing it in Spring AMQP. I did this in pure Java, based on the example in RabbitMQ's website. I passively declare the queue, check its consumer count, if it is 0, then start to consume it.

Here's the code.

```java
ConnectionFactory factory = new ConnectionFactory();
factory.setHost("localhost");
Connection connection = factory.newConnection();
Channel channel = connection.createChannel();

int count = channel.queueDeclarePassive(QUEUE_NAME).getConsumerCount();

System.out.println("count is "+count);
if (count == 0) {
    channel.queueDeclare(QUEUE_NAME, false, false, false, null);

    System.out.println(" [*] Waiting for messages. To exit press CTRL+C");

    DeliverCallback deliverCallback = (consumerTag, delivery) -> {
        String message = new String(delivery.getBody(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        System.out.println(" [x] Received '" + message + "'");
    };
    channel.basicConsume(QUEUE_NAME, true, deliverCallback, consumerTag -> { });
} else{
    System.out.println("subscribed by some other processor(s)");
}
```

I also can check the subscriber count in Spring AMQP this way. But it is too late, because it already listens to the queue.

```java
@RabbitListener(queues = "q1")
public void receivedMessageQ1(String message, Channel channel){
    try {
        int q1 = channel.queueDeclarePassive("q1").getConsumerCount();
        // do something.
    } catch (IOException e) {
        System.out.println("exception occurred");
    }
}
```

In a nutshell, I want to consume a queue based on its consumer count. I hope I am clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set the `exclusive` flag on the `@RabbitListener`; RabbitMQ will only allow one instance to consume. The other instance(s) will attempt to listen every 5 seconds (by default). To increase the interval, set the container factory's `recoveryBackOff`.

```java
@SpringBootApplication
public class So56319999Application {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(So56319999Application.class, args);
    }

    @RabbitListener(queues = "so56319999", exclusive = true)
    public void listen (String in) {

    }

    @Bean
    public Queue queue() {
        return new Queue("so56319999");
    }

}
```

Comment: So, if the current instance drops, will the other ones have the chance of listening? Does it have any relation to exclusive queues? Since exclusive queues are getting deleted when connection is closed.

Comment: When the active consumer dies, another instance will start consuming (exclusively). No, exclusive consumers have nothing to do with exclusive queues.